# Cannot find Property Manager option in Visual Studio (not Express version)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to work with the Property Sheet of a project.  I followed instruction on msdn to try to find Property Manager under View, but I do not see Property Manager as a menu option under Tool.  I only saw Property Pages and Properties Window.  I tried both options but they do not seem to be where I can create a property sheet.  My Visual Studio version is as follows: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel.  Can anyone please give a pointer?  Thanks.

Comment: TLDR -- it's under `View->Other Window`, lads, it's there!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try resetting your `View` menu, `Property Manager` should indeed be there.

1. Go to `Tools` -> `Customize`.
2. In the popup window, select the `Commands` tab.
3. Select the `Menu bar:` button, and in the dropdown menu select `View`
4. Click `Reset All` and confirm.

This should restore `Property Manager` to your `View` menu.

Comment: I did what you said but I can't find it on `view` menu. I found it on `View->Other Windows` as other answers said

Answer (score 89):

I finally found mine under **View**->**Other Windows**, near the bottom.

Comment: In VS2013 the `Property Mananager` is also located under `View->Other Windows`

Comment: Worked for VS 2019

Comment: Worked for VS 2019, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 19):

To see the Property Manager you need to have Expert Settings enabled. You can find this option in:

Tools -> Settings

Comment: No Tools->settings option in VS 2010

Comment: I use VS 2010 Express and found it right at Tools->Settings->Expert Settings (in fact I use it in german, so I got: "Erweiterte Einstellungen")

Comment: you helped me alot with that, unlocked a lot of options i was looking for in my properties window. thanks

Comment: This is it for me, not other windows or the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

It is under **View** --> **Other Windows** --> **Properties Manager**. It works.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I restored the Property Manager menu item in Visual Studio 2013:

1. Select Tools\Customize
2. Select the Commands Tab and Menu Bar
3. Under the dropdown beside Menu Bar, select "View | Other Windows" (or wherever you'd like to put it)
4. Click "Add Command..." and select the View category
5. Find and select Property Manager from Commands and click OK

Comment: It was a relief just to find out where the Property Manager was so I could at least use it

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was just in the **VIEW** toolbar - almost in the bottom. Running VS2013 Pro update 3

Answer (score 2):

Property Manager is a moot utility now.  Since the property sheet is defined for each project, it can be edited by right clicking on the project and selecting properties. If you need to edit multiple projects once, just select all the projects you want to effect a change and do the right clicking trick.
This brings up the same property pages as it would from Property Manager.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. There is no Property Manager (I tried everything above) in my copy of VS 2012 Professional.

Answer (score 2):

View > Property Manager or **View > Other Windows > Property Manager**, please try this

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me.  What worked for me is:

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings -> ... -> Visual C++ Development Settings

Answer (score 1):

Despite I selected Visual C# settings at first use, for some reason, VC++ settings were ON, causing the visual components property window to not show up while pressing F4. 
Selecting Visual C# settings ( in Tools | Import and export settings... | Reset All ) made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the given answers worked for me here are my two cents.

Like any well hidden menu in Visual Studio this one can be found by opening `Tools -> Options... -> Environment -> Keyboard` and searching for "View.PropertyManager". There you can give it a global shortcut. While this only helps if you know the name of the menu or command you are looking for it's much faster go through a bunch of guesses this way than by randomly browsing menus.