# Default Visual Studio Project Settings to Use "rvalueCast"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, casting, visual-studio-2015

I've made a <sarcasm>shocking</sarcasam> discovery: [Visual Studio 2015 is not C++11 compliant by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37969114/2642059)

I can follow the steps [I listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969114/what-does-static-castt-do-to-a-t?noredirect=1#comment63397525_37969300) for each project, or use Notepad++ or similar to do a files replace, but I do notice that the "Command Line" Properties have a checkbox: "Inherit from parent or project defaults"

[image]

Is there a way to add "/Zc:rvalueCast" to my "project defaults" so everything will use it, including future projects?

Comment: wow Well done. I have confirmed this to be true and MSVS 2017 doesn't have that enabled by default... Would you still recommend I enable this?

Comment: @Nik-Lz My recommendation would be to set this flag as it makes Visual C++ standard compliant in this regard.

Comment: Yes, definitely. It broke a large project of mine, but thankfully the damage was minor and I just managed to fix it.

Comment: I found out that starting with MSVS 2017 the `/permissive` option which is enabled by default automatically enables `/Zc:rvalueCast` and another option which makes compilation standard conforming. Therefore if you're compiling through the IDE this is no longer an issue. I didn't notice this before, but I did now so I've come to report it.

Comment: @Nik-Lz Thank you so much for the update. Sadly I haven't had the opportunity to test the newer versions of Visual Studio at work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the microsoft.cpp.win32.user property sheet accordingly.

To access it, open the property manager for your solution. (It's sometimes tricky to find the property manager - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179201/cannot-find-property-manager-option-in-visual-studio-not-express-version)) Then, in the Property Manager, drill down, until you find the user property sheet as shown below. Then right-click and select Properties and edit any settings you like. After you're done, don't forget to save the property sheet (Right-click and select save)

[image]

Comment: So it seems like the "Release" Properties inherit from the "Debug" ones, but it looks like I will need to also edit "Debug | x64" > "Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user" right?

Comment: @JonathanMee Yup. You could also create your own property sheet (like the Common_DefaultPropertySheet in my screenshot). It gives you more control, but you have to remember to include it in your projects